# mshtml.dll in GAC?

Tags: clickonce, gac, mshtml

Having added `msHtml.dll` to a project of mine, I can see the dll is taken from MS-Office tools and NOT from the GAC.

Consequently, it adds over 7 Megabytes to my ClickOnce project, which is bad for downloaders.

It seems I needed it in order to directly edit HTML document within winforms WebBrowser.

Does somebody know a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You usually can't legally redistribute Microsoft DLLs with your product anyways. Check for it as a pre-requirement to installation and then configure your application to use it wherever it lives on the target machine.

Comment: Ok, I got your point. My problem is I NEED to edit the webbrowser hosted document, by setting the document.designmode property to ON. And the webBrowser.HTMLDocument just doesn't let me do that: "unknown property"!...

Comment: You should open a different question for that, then.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to argue the legalities of including that assembly, but I WILL tell you this. If you do publish it, it will cache it on the user's machine in its own folder AND in the deployment. Then when you publish an update, when ClickOnce updates, it will check the one on the server against the local cache on the client machine, and if it hasn't changed, will copy it from the cached folder on the client machine. So it won't copy it across the network more than once.